# 50/50 chance of getting element size with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, window, image-size

I have weird problem which i find very difficult to reproduce on jsfiddle. Best i could do was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SUst2/) but this works every time printing out correct width and height every time.

Same time it works only like 50% of times. Other times it gets 0 as image size and width.

My HTML is:

```
<div role="main" id="main">
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns" style="float:none;">
            <img src="/media/files/clientfiles/test1_X-1a_.png" id="editorImage">
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">zalalal</div>
</div>
</div>
```

matching css is:

```
#main {
width: 1000px;
margin: 50px auto;
background: white;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
color: #666;}

.row {
width: 1000px;
max-width: 100%;
min-width: 768px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.row .twelve {
width: 75%;
}

.column, .columns {
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
padding: 0 10px;
position: relative;
}
```

and javascript is

```
jQuery(function($){
        var element = $('#editorImage');
        console.log(element);
        console.log(element.width());
        console.log(element.height());
        console.log(element.outerWidth());
        console.log(element.outerHeight());
        console.log(element.offsetWidth);
        console.log(element.offsetHeight);
});
```

at first i thought its related to trying to get element size before document ready, but `jQuery(function($...` should take care of that, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should trap on `window.load`, not `document.ready`.

The latter waits for the DOM tree to become ready, but the former is necessary if you want to also wait for all images to load, too.

```
$(function() {
    // do DOM ready related stuff here
});

$(window).on('load', function() {
    // do image related stuff here
});
```

Comment: Personally I disagree, you shouldn't really be interacting with DOM elements until the page is fully loaded. Just my opinion.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper IMHO it's perfectly acceptable to do things like add event handlers, etc.  Just don't rely on any properties having their final values.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I disagree, it is perfectly acceptable to interact with the DOM at any point, if you want to interact with it once its ready use the ready, the normal place to do things, however if you need to wait for images to be loaded then you must use load, otherwise they will not have widths/height etc set.  However I prefer my answer as it doesnt rely on all images to have loaded if there happen to be a lot on one page.

Comment: yeah... was probably the issue that image was not loaded. using window load event fixed it all. Thanks.

Comment: @Zayatzz be careful with this, as my answer pointed out this will wait till everything has finished loading not just until the particular image you want has finished loading, hence why I use a slightly different way of doing things when it comes to images.

Comment: @JonTaylor yes, he should do as much as possible in `document.ready`, and only do the stuff that depends on the images being loaded in `window.onload`.

Comment: @Alnitak I would actually say he should do as much in `document.ready` and if needed do things in an `img.load` per image rather than in the `window.onload`.  Take an example where you have 100 images load and your code only depends on the first image theres no point waiting for the rest of the images to load, instead doing what you want on the img load is much better.  I tend to stick to this whether im dealing with one or more images.  At least thats the way I tend to prefer doing things. But each to their own.

Comment: @JonTaylor Agreed - using `img.onload` as each image loads would often be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the image is loaded ?

Try get the dimensions after $(window).load(function); or $(img).load(function);

Answer (score 1):

Others have suggested using a `$(window).load` however I would suggest potentially a different option.

Since you may want to style immediately after a specific image has loaded, for example lets say you have 100 images load and each row styling is only dependent on one image, you don't want to wait for all images to load.

You can use the `.load` function on an image, however you have to be careful since some browsers will not call this function if the image is stored in the cache, for this reason I split my functions up as follows, you can pass parameters if needed although for my example I will leave them out.

```
function imageLoadedFunction() {
    //some code to execute once the image has loaded
    //(you could pass a reference to the image in the function)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $image = $('#imageId');
    if($image.width() != 0)
        imageLoadedFunction();
});

$('#imageId').load(function() {
    imageLoadedFunction();
});
```

This ensures that if the image is not cached the `load()` function will be called once the image has finished loading, if the image is cached then the function will be called from within the document ready.